# Docusign email Title

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docuSign via the api and am successfully setting the recipients EmailNotification.Subject and .EmailBlurb

However, I need to be able to change the title. It currently defaults to 'Please review and sign your document'. I am using V1.1 of the email engine as my client does not want to use V2 at this time and I can see [[EmailTitle]] in the resource file but nowhere to actually set the variable.

There isn't anything obvious in the api.

Am I missing something? Or is this just not an optional element of the emails?

Thank you,

Comment: @jamie stonehill What do you mean when you say you can set the Email Subject but not the "Title"?  Aren't they the same?  For instance, when I set the Email Subject property in a given request that overrides the default "Please review and sign your document" subject on my emails, and when I login to the web Console and look at the envelope I see the same subject I set.

Comment: The subject is the text that you see under subject in your email client. The title is in the body text of the email but is separate from the email blurb. It is dynamic. For an envelope sent asking for a signature it will say 'Please review and sign your document' but if you set the envelope to be carbon copied to another address the title will be 'Carbon copy'. I like having this as I do use the cc feature, I was just hoping that I could change the wording on the signature request emails. Its interesting that the title is being changed for you. Maybe its because I'm using the old email engine.